# boolean index if row equal value for all unique values in another column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to return a boolean index using separate columns. Where `End` is in `Item`, I want to return False.

I'm meeting those conditions but I want to account for all unique values in `Seq`. For each unique group in `Seq`, if any row matches the previous condition, then return False for all those unique groups.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Item' : ['Start','A','B','B','G','Start','A','B','B','A','X','Start','A','H'],        
    })

End = ['X','Y','Z']

df['Seq'] = df['Item'].eq('Start').groupby(df['Item'].eq('Start').cumsum()).transform('idxmax')


m2 = df.Item.isin(End)
```

out:

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10    False
11     True
12     True
13     True
```

intended out:

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12     True
13     True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `idxmax`, use `max` and then negate the result:

```
~df.Item.isin(End).groupby(df.Item.eq('Start').cumsum()).transform('max')

0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12     True
13     True
Name: Item, dtype: bool
```

To exclude row with `Start`:

```
~(df.Item.isin(End).groupby(df.Item.eq('Start').cumsum()).transform('max') & df.Item.ne('Start'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Group the boolean mask `m2` by `Seq` and `transform` with `any` then negate the output

```
~(m2.groupby(df['Seq']).transform('any'))
```

---

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12     True
13     True
Name: Item, dtype: bool
```